# How to make numbers not repeat from a specific list

Tags: vb.net

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to make numbers not repeat from a specific list that I have created.  Can someone please help?  Once a number is chosen I dont want it to be chosen again.  Seems like numbers.Remove(number) isnt working

```
 Private Sub GetMoneyRand()
    If randomLog.Count = numberList.Count Then
        MsgBox("No more number for random")
        Return
    End If
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        Dim rndDummy As Integer = CInt(numMax.Value * Rnd())
        lblRandomNumber.Text = rndDummy
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(30)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next

    Randomize()
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)
    numbers.AddRange(New Integer() {1, 16, 31, 46, 61, 10, 15, 14, 75, 33, 11, 19, 25, 44, 50, 72, 2, 44, 20, 30})

    Dim number As Integer = numbers(r.Next(0, numbers.Count))
    For x As Integer = 1 To 20
        numbers.Remove(number)

    Next
    randomLog.Add(number)
    lblRandomNumber.Text = number
    numberList(number).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
```

Comment: Make an array as global variable to which you append each number that has been chosen. Once new number is selected, you check if its present in the global array.

Comment: What is randomLog? What is numberList? What is numMax? It is impossible for me to reproduce you error without knowing these things. Your question should be minimal, complete and reproducible.

Comment: It appears you are using 2 different random generators in the same Sub. Why? Get rid of Application.DoEvents. You don't need it. I am guessing lblRandomNumber is a label. Why are your overwriting its text property 100 times? Why the Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Your  numbers.Remove(number) loop is trying to remove the same number on each iteration. The value of number is set outside the loop.

Comment: 'lblRandomNumber.Text = number' You declare number as an Integer and then try to assign it to a .Text property which takes a string. You need to turn on Option Strict.

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

To create a list with unique random numbers use the `.Contains` method of `List(of T)` before adding the new random to the list.

```
Private numbers As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 16, 31, 46, 61, 10, 15, 14, 75, 33, 11, 19, 25, 44, 50, 72, 2, 44, 20, 30}
Private r As New Random

Private Sub AddRandomsToList()
    Dim i = r.Next(0, 21)
    If numbers.Contains(i) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry that number is already in the list. Try Again.")
    Else
        numbers.Add(i)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddRandomsToList()
End Sub
```

To remove duplicates from an existing list use the `.Distinct` extension method. It will return a new list of unique elements when you call `.ToList`

```
Private numbers As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 16, 1, 46, 61, 16, 15, 14, 61, 46, 11, 19, 25, 46, 50, 50, 2, 44, 20, 30}
Private r As New Random
Private Sub RemoveDuplicate()
    Dim UniqueNumbers = numbers.Distinct().ToList
    For Each i In UniqueNumbers
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a stack or a queue. They both remove items as they are used.

```vb
Private numbers As Integer() = {1, 16, 31, 46, 61, 10, 15, 14, 75, 33, 11, 19, 25, 44, 50, 72, 2, 44, 20, 30}
Private rng As New Random

Private Sub OutputNumbersInRandomOrder()
    Dim randomisedNumbers As New Queue(Of Integer)(numbers.OrderBy(Function(n) rng.NextDouble()))

    Do Until randomisedNumbers.Count = 0
        Dim number = randomisedNumbers.Dequeue()

        Console.WriteLine(number)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Each time you call `Dequeue`, the first number is removed from the list and returned. You can do this as many times as you like, creating a new queue each time the previous one is empty, e.g.

```vb
Private numbers As Integer() = {1, 16, 31, 46, 61, 10, 15, 14, 75, 33, 11, 19, 25, 44, 50, 72, 2, 44, 20, 30}
Private randomisedNumbers As Queue(Of Integer)
Private rng As New Random

Private Function GetRandomNumber() As Integer
    If randomisedNumbers Is Nothing OrElse randomisedNumbers.Count = 0 Then
        randomisedNumbers = New Queue(Of Integer)(numbers.OrderBy(Function(n) rng.NextDouble()))
    End If

    Return randomisedNumbers.Dequeue()
End Function
```

You can do the same thing with a `Stack(Of Integer)` and calling `Pop`. The only difference is that a stack takes items from the other end - LIFO instead of FIFO. As the items are randomised and all added at the same time, there's really no difference in the outcome, especially given that calling `OrderByDescending` would reverse the outcomes of the two types anyway. To illustrate:

```vb
Dim numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Dim q1 As New Queue(Of Integer)(numbers)
Dim s1 As New Stack(Of Integer)(numbers)

Console.WriteLine("q1:")

Do Until q1.Count = 0
    Console.WriteLine(q1.Dequeue())
Loop

Console.WriteLine("s1:")

Do Until s1.Count = 0
    Console.WriteLine(s1.Pop())
Loop

Array.Reverse(numbers)

Dim q2 As New Queue(Of Integer)(numbers)
Dim s2 As New Stack(Of Integer)(numbers)

Console.WriteLine("q2:")

Do Until q2.Count = 0
    Console.WriteLine(q2.Dequeue())
Loop

Console.WriteLine("s2:")

Do Until s2.Count = 0
    Console.WriteLine(s2.Pop())
Loop
```

Output:

```
q1:
1
2
3
4
5
s1:
5
4
3
2
1
q2:
5
4
3
2
1
s2:
1
2
3
4
5
```